# Как рядом с radio вывести кнопки сабмита формы

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

```
 $builder->add("activeHealthPlan", ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'choices'      => $hps,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded'     => true,
                'multiple'     => false,
                'data'         => $active
            ]);
```

Есть такой формтайп который отображает радиобаттоны, в общем справа нужно возле каждого добавить кнопку сабмит, кроме того который активен.

Comment: Радио батоны :D

Comment: в общем уже не нужно, но я нашел решение через твиг